# Difference in execution plan between Xpath and cts:search in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, query-performance

Running `xdmp:plan()` on an Xpath, in the execution plan I found  the following:
`<qry:info-trace>Selected n fragments</qry:info-trace>`
But running `xdmp:plan()` on `cts:search(/Xpath,cts:and-query(()))` , I got 
  `<qry:info-trace>Selected n fragments to filter</qry:info-trace>`

Why is "to filter" missing in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 7.0-3 and `cts:search`:

```
xdmp:plan(cts:search(/a/b/c, cts:and-query(())))
=>
...
<qry:info-trace>Selected N fragments to filter</qry:info-trace>
...
```

Whereas with XPath:

```
xdmp:plan(/a/b/c)
=>
...
<qry:info-trace>Selected N fragments</qry:info-trace>
....
```

The difference is mostly aesthetic. The `cts:search` function accepts an `unfiltered` option, while XPath has no such option: XPath results are always filtered. The plan only mentions filtering when unfiltered search is possible, **and** filtering is enabled.

```
xdmp:plan(cts:search(/a/b/c, cts:and-query(()), 'unfiltered'))
=>
...
<qry:info-trace>Selected N fragments</qry:info-trace>
....
```

See https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered for background on why filtering is enabled by default, and why you might want to disable it in certain circumstances.